# Admin Block Page Custom Theme

Tags: 6, theming

I am trying to use the garland theme on the blocks page rather than using my custom theme.

I have found this question:
[Force block page to use admin theme?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8935/force-block-page-to-use-admin-theme)

Which has given me a code snippet to use. I have placed this in the modules/block/block.admin.inc file on line 36.

The theme is still my custom theme and i must be doing something wrong. If possible i would rather not use a module.

The code i am using:

```
function mytheme_init() {
  // Hardcode the administration theme onto the blocks page
  if ($_GET['q'] == 'admin/build/block') {
    global $custom_theme;
    $theme = 'garland';
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI it's a REALLY bad idea to hack core.  Firstly, God knows what could break, and secondly..whatever changes you make will likely be over-written if/when you update core.

To answer your question, you're calling the $custom_theme as you should, but then assigning a Garland to `$theme`, which isn't used.

Try the following:

```
function mytheme_init() {
  // Hardcode the administration theme onto the blocks page
  if ($_GET['q'] == 'admin/build/block') {
    global $custom_theme;
    $custom_theme = 'garland';
  }
}
```

In your custom theme's `template.php` instead of in `block.admin.inc`.  Make sure you change `mytheme` to whatever your custom theme's name is (e.g. `my_custom_theme_init` or `custom_init`).

You might also want to look at the [Administration Theme](http://drupal.org/project/admin_theme) module or the [Themekey](http://drupal.org/project/themekey) module for admin theme options/theme switching.

[Themekey](http://drupal.org/project/themekey) sounds like a pretty good bet for ease of use:

> ThemeKey allows you to define simple or sophisticated theme-switching
>   rules which allow automatic selection of a theme depending on current
>   path, taxonomy terms, language, node-type, and many, many other
>   properties. It can also be easily extended to support additional
>   properties exposed by other modules.

**EDIT**

I forgot, the [Admin](http://drupal.org/project/admin) module also comes with an admin theme option, and a pretty decent admin menu for end users (clients etc.).